# Issue TypeError: argument must be a string or number

Tags: python, label-encoding

There is only one categorical column and I want to encode it, it is working fine on notebook but when it is being uploaded to aicrowd platform it is creating this trouble.
There are totally 3 categorical features where one is the target feature, one is the row of ids and after excluding them for the training I am left with one feature.

```
df[['intersection_pos_rel_centre']]
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le=LabelEncoder()
df[['intersection_pos_rel_centre']]=le.fit_transform(df[['intersection_pos_rel_centre']])
df[['intersection_pos_rel_centre']]
```

My error is

```
Selecting runtime language: python
[NbConvertApp] Converting notebook predict.ipynb to notebook
[NbConvertApp] Executing notebook with kernel: python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/bin/jupyter-nbconvert", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 254, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 350, in start
    self.convert_notebooks()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 524, in convert_notebooks
    self.convert_single_notebook(notebook_filename)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 489, in convert_single_notebook
    output, resources = self.export_single_notebook(notebook_filename, resources, input_buffer=input_buffer)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/nbconvertapp.py", line 418, in export_single_notebook
    output, resources = self.exporter.from_filename(notebook_filename, resources=resources)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 181, in from_filename
    return self.from_file(f, resources=resources, **kw)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 199, in from_file
    return self.from_notebook_node(nbformat.read(file_stream, as_version=4), resources=resources, **kw)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/notebook.py", line 32, in from_notebook_node
    nb_copy, resources = super().from_notebook_node(nb, resources, **kw)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 143, in from_notebook_node
    nb_copy, resources = self._preprocess(nb_copy, resources)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/exporters/exporter.py", line 318, in _preprocess
    nbc, resc = preprocessor(nbc, resc)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/base.py", line 47, in __call__
    return self.preprocess(nb, resources)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 79, in preprocess
    self.execute()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbclient/util.py", line 74, in wrapped
    return just_run(coro(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbclient/util.py", line 53, in just_run
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbclient/client.py", line 553, in async_execute
    await self.async_execute_cell(
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 123, in async_execute_cell
    cell, resources = self.preprocess_cell(cell, self.resources, cell_index)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/execute.py", line 146, in preprocess_cell
    cell = run_sync(NotebookClient.async_execute_cell)(self, cell, index, store_history=self.store_history)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbclient/util.py", line 74, in wrapped
    return just_run(coro(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbclient/util.py", line 53, in just_run
    return loop.run_until_complete(coro)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nest_asyncio.py", line 98, in run_until_complete
    return f.result()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/asyncio/futures.py", line 178, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 280, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbclient/client.py", line 852, in async_execute_cell
    self._check_raise_for_error(cell, exec_reply)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nbclient/client.py", line 760, in _check_raise_for_error
    raise CellExecutionError.from_cell_and_msg(cell, exec_reply_content)
nbclient.exceptions.CellExecutionError: An error occurred while executing the following cell:
------------------
df[['intersection_pos_rel_centre']]
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le=LabelEncoder()
df[['intersection_pos_rel_centre']]=le.fit_transform(df[['intersection_pos_rel_centre']])
df[['intersection_pos_rel_centre']]
------------------


TypeError: argument must be a string or number
```

Comment: I am just thinking the single quote which is used in 'intersection_pos_rel_centre' might have been converted to a special character when imported to aicrowd . Try editing these quotes again in aicrowd, Just a guess

Comment: It is not the case I changed and I tried it